# How to calcualte the area under the curve defined by a Prometheus gauge

Tags: prometheus, metrics

Given a Prometheus Gauge with values >= 0, how do I calculate (approximate) the area between the values and the (imaginary) Y axis on a given time frame?

Comment: Prometheus doesn't provide such a functionality, but this may be calculated with `integrate` function from [MetricsQL](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/wiki/MetricsQL): `integrate(gauge[time_frame])` would return the area for `gauge` over the given `time_frame`.